# Format string to look like mysql query c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I want to display string:

```
string s = "CREATE TABLE shop (article INT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL DEFAULT '0000' NOT NULL,dealer CHAR(20)DEFAULT ''NOT NULL,price   DOUBLE(16,2) DEFAULT '0.00' NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(article, dealer)); INSERT INTO shop VALUES..."
```

on text box and i want to like this(like in workbench):

```
CREATE TABLE shop (
 article INT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL DEFAULT '0000' NOT NULL,
 dealer  CHAR(20)DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
 price   DOUBLE(16,2)DEFAULT '0.00' NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(article, dealer));
INSERT INTO shop VALUES...
```

Is there any way to format string, or any other solution?

Comment: Insert the appropriate newline characters (Environment.NewLine)

Comment: No that's not helpful, because I have a lot of stings of this type, and they are not the same, so need a function which will format me any string of this type to type displayed above

Comment: You need to use Regex to parse the string and then use groups to form new string with newlines inserted at proper locations. Will post the working code sample later if you need it.

Comment: if you are reading this query statement from mysql, and then want to display it in a formatted way, you will have to write your own custom code. C# and .NET Framework intrinsically do not have something that will do what you want. There might be some 3rd party software/library to do it

Comment: @Rupesh thanks for the answer i think that will be helpful, can you please post code sample?

Comment: @Vikhram yes I read query statement from mysql. Do you now for any of 3rd party sotware/library that can be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open-source library that can help you to achieve that. It is called Poor Man's T-SQL Formatter. I'm not sure if it fully supports all the MySQL syntax, but it gave me good results with pretty complex queries.

It is packaged in a NuGet, although it seems to be using the old .NET 2.0. You can find a more recent compilation in the official project website:
http://www.architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx

Comment: Does this answer your question? If it does, please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: http://www.architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx is great, but doesn't fully support MySql syntax :-(

Answer (score 0):

Although, it is late but for the interest of those viewers who would like to experiment with code as an alternative to third party library, following is the code segment:

```
    string s = "CREATE TABLE shop (article INT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL DEFAULT '0000' NOT NULL,dealer CHAR(20)DEFAULT ''NOT NULL,price   DOUBLE(16,2) DEFAULT '0.00' NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(article, dealer)); INSERT INTO shop VALUES (0001, 'dealer-0001', 100.10); INSERT INTO shop VALUES (0002, 'dealer-0002', 200.20);";

    Regex rx = new Regex("(CREATE\\s+TABLE\\s+\\w+\\s+\\()([^;]+);\\s*(INSERT\\s+INTO\\s+\\w+\\s+VALUES\\s+(\\([^;]+);\\s*)+");
    Match m = rx.Match(s);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine(m.Groups[1].Value);     // get CREATE TABLE tblname (
    sb.AppendLine(m.Groups[2].Value.Replace("NULL,", "NULL,\r\n") + ";");   //    put every column definition in separate lines
    foreach (Capture p in m.Groups[3].Captures)
       sb.AppendLine(p.Value);   // get each INSERT statement in separate line
    textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();   // put everything in the Multiline TextBox
```

To use above code, create a blank WinForm, add Multiline TextBox and a Button, put above code inside the Click event of button.